# How to split folder of images into test/training/validation sets with stratified sampling?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very large folder of images, as well as a CSV file containing the class labels for each of those images. Because it's all in one giant folder, I'd like to split them up into training/test/validation sets; maybe create three new folders and move images into each based on a Python script of some kind. I'd like to do stratified sampling so I can keep the % of classes the same across all three sets.

What would be the approach to go about making a script that can do this?

Answer (score 68):

Use the python library split-folder.

```
pip install split-folders
```

Let all the images be stored in `Data` folder.
Then apply as follows:

```
import splitfolders
splitfolders.ratio('Data', output="output", seed=1337, ratio=(.8, 0.1,0.1))
```

On running the above code snippet, it will create 3 folders in the `output` directory:

- train
- val
- test

The number of images in each folder can be varied using the values in the `ratio` argument`(train:val:test)`.

Comment: THIS little library is a true gem. I was pulling my hair out literally for an entire day until I stumbled across this. Gotto love SO and Github.

Comment: its not "split_folders", but "splitfolders". the corrent code is:

`import splitfolders
splitfolders.ratio('Data', output="output", seed=1337, ratio=(.8, 0.1,0.1))`

Comment: @KhalilAl-rahmanYossefi is right, the function is called `splitfolders`. More information at https://pypi.org/project/split-folders/

Comment: Works flawlessly and handles the splitting for multiple classes.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes!

Comment: You can use both 'splitfolders' or 'split_folders'. It works for both flawlessly.

Comment: Can splitfolders splits with stratified sampling? @AVISHEKGARAIN

Answer (score 13):

I ran into a similar problem myself. All my images were stored in two folders. "Project/Data2/DPN+" and "Project/Data2/DPN-". It was a binary classification problem. The two classes were "DPN+" and "DPN-". Both of these class folders had .png in them. My objective was to distribute the dataset into training, validation and testing folders. Each of these new folders will have 2 more folders - "DPN+" and "DPN-" - inside them indicating the class. For partition, I used 70:15:15 distribution. I am a beginner in python so, please let me know if I made any mistakes.

Following is my code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import shutil

# # Creating Train / Val / Test folders (One time use)
root_dir = 'Data2'
posCls = '/DPN+'
negCls = '/DPN-'

os.makedirs(root_dir +'/train' + posCls)
os.makedirs(root_dir +'/train' + negCls)
os.makedirs(root_dir +'/val' + posCls)
os.makedirs(root_dir +'/val' + negCls)
os.makedirs(root_dir +'/test' + posCls)
os.makedirs(root_dir +'/test' + negCls)

# Creating partitions of the data after shuffeling
currentCls = posCls
src = "Data2"+currentCls # Folder to copy images from

allFileNames = os.listdir(src)
np.random.shuffle(allFileNames)
train_FileNames, val_FileNames, test_FileNames = np.split(np.array(allFileNames),
                                                          [int(len(allFileNames)*0.7), int(len(allFileNames)*0.85)])


train_FileNames = [src+'/'+ name for name in train_FileNames.tolist()]
val_FileNames = [src+'/' + name for name in val_FileNames.tolist()]
test_FileNames = [src+'/' + name for name in test_FileNames.tolist()]

print('Total images: ', len(allFileNames))
print('Training: ', len(train_FileNames))
print('Validation: ', len(val_FileNames))
print('Testing: ', len(test_FileNames))

# Copy-pasting images
for name in train_FileNames:
    shutil.copy(name, "Data2/train"+currentCls)

for name in val_FileNames:
    shutil.copy(name, "Data2/val"+currentCls)

for name in test_FileNames:
    shutil.copy(name, "Data2/test"+currentCls)
```

Comment: This should be marked as the right solution.

Answer (score 7):

Taking Steven White's answer above and altering it a bit as there was a minor issue with the splitting. Also, the files were being saved in the main folder instead of train/test/val folders respectively.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import shutil
import pandas as pd


def train_test_split():
    print("########### Train Test Val Script started ###########")
    #data_csv = pd.read_csv("DataSet_Final.csv") ##Use if you have classes saved in any .csv file

    root_dir = 'New_folder_to_be_created'
    classes_dir = ['class 1', 'class 2', 'class 3', 'class 4']

    #for name in data_csv['names'].unique()[:10]:
    #    classes_dir.append(name)

    processed_dir = 'Existing_folder_to_take_images_from'

    val_ratio = 0.20
    test_ratio = 0.20

    for cls in classes_dir:
        # Creating partitions of the data after shuffeling
        print("$$$$$$$ Class Name " + cls + " $$$$$$$")
        src = processed_dir +"//" + cls  # Folder to copy images from

        allFileNames = os.listdir(src)
        np.random.shuffle(allFileNames)
        train_FileNames, val_FileNames, test_FileNames = np.split(np.array(allFileNames),
                                                                  [int(len(allFileNames) * (1 - (val_ratio + test_ratio))),
                                                                   int(len(allFileNames) * (1 - val_ratio)),
                                                                   ])

        train_FileNames = [src + '//' + name for name in train_FileNames.tolist()]
        val_FileNames = [src + '//' + name for name in val_FileNames.tolist()]
        test_FileNames = [src + '//' + name for name in test_FileNames.tolist()]

        print('Total images: '+ str(len(allFileNames)))
        print('Training: '+ str(len(train_FileNames)))
        print('Validation: '+  str(len(val_FileNames)))
        print('Testing: '+ str(len(test_FileNames)))

        # # Creating Train / Val / Test folders (One time use)
        os.makedirs(root_dir + '/train//' + cls)
        os.makedirs(root_dir + '/val//' + cls)
        os.makedirs(root_dir + '/test//' + cls)

        # Copy-pasting images
        for name in train_FileNames:
            shutil.copy(name, root_dir + '/train//' + cls)

        for name in val_FileNames:
            shutil.copy(name, root_dir + '/val//' + cls)

        for name in test_FileNames:
            shutil.copy(name, root_dir + '/test//' + cls)

    print("########### Train Test Val Script Ended ###########")

train_test_split()
```

Answer (score 6):

## UPDATE (2022):

I have developed a python package called python_splitter to automate the whole process in one line. This will auto-generate Train-Test-Val or Train-Test folders .
Read more : https://github.com/bharatadk/python_splitter

```
! pip install python_splitter 
import python_splitter
python_splitter.split_from_folder("SOURCE_FOLDER", train=0.5, test=0.3, val=0.2)
```

### Old Method ( Manual Process )

```
**I have made better code which you have to run once **

## I made this for TB vs Normal image datasets by improving above code
## import libraries

import os
import numpy as np
import shutil
import random

# creating train / val /test
root_dir = 'TB_Chest_Radiography_Database/'
new_root = 'AllDatasets/'
classes = ['Normal', 'Tuberculosis']

for cls in classes:
    os.makedirs(root_dir + new_root+ 'train/' + cls)
    os.makedirs(root_dir +new_root +'val/' + cls)
    os.makedirs(root_dir +new_root + 'test/' + cls)
    
## creating partition of the data after shuffeling

for cls in classes:
    src = root_dir + cls # folder to copy images from
    print(src)

    allFileNames = os.listdir(src)
    np.random.shuffle(allFileNames)

    ## here 0.75 = training ratio , (0.95-0.75) = validation ratio , (1-0.95) =  
    ##training ratio  
    train_FileNames,val_FileNames,test_FileNames = np.split(np.array(allFileNames),[int(len(allFileNames)*0.75),int(len(allFileNames)*0.95)])

    # #Converting file names from array to list

    train_FileNames = [src+'/'+ name for name in train_FileNames]
    val_FileNames = [src+'/' + name for name in val_FileNames]
    test_FileNames = [src+'/' + name for name in test_FileNames]

    print('Total images  : '+ cls + ' ' +str(len(allFileNames)))
    print('Training : '+ cls + ' '+str(len(train_FileNames)))
    print('Validation : '+ cls + ' ' +str(len(val_FileNames)))
    print('Testing : '+ cls + ' '+str(len(test_FileNames)))
    
    ## Copy pasting images to target directory

    for name in train_FileNames:
        shutil.copy(name, root_dir + new_root+'train/'+cls )


    for name in val_FileNames:
        shutil.copy(name, root_dir +new_root+'val/'+cls )


    for name in test_FileNames:
        shutil.copy(name,root_dir + new_root+'test/'+cls )
```

Comment: I had to edit this a bit to adapt to my case scenario, but this comment has saved me a lot of time and is the most realistic and adaptable. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had similar task. My images and corresponding annotations in XML format were stored in one folder.
I made train and test folder but I used origin folder as validation folder after splitting files *(see the script)*.

Here is my script to split files into into test/training/validation sets:

```
import os
from random import choice
import shutil

#arrays to store file names
imgs =[]
xmls =[]

#setup dir names
trainPath = 'train'
valPath = 'val'
testPath = 'test'
crsPath = 'img' #dir where images and annotations stored

#setup ratio (val ratio = rest of the files in origin dir after splitting into train and test)
train_ratio = 0.8
test_ratio = 0.1


#total count of imgs
totalImgCount = len(os.listdir(crsPath))/2

#soring files to corresponding arrays
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(crsPath):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.xml'):
            xmls.append(filename)
        else:
            imgs.append(filename)


#counting range for cycles
countForTrain = int(len(imgs)*train_ratio)
countForTest = int(len(imgs)*test_ratio)

#cycle for train dir
for x in range(countForTrain):

    fileJpg = choice(imgs) # get name of random image from origin dir
    fileXml = fileJpg[:-4] +'.xml' # get name of corresponding annotation file

    #move both files into train dir
    shutil.move(os.path.join(crsPath, fileJpg), os.path.join(trainPath, fileJpg))
    shutil.move(os.path.join(crsPath, fileXml), os.path.join(trainPath, fileXml))

    #remove files from arrays
    imgs.remove(fileJpg)
    xmls.remove(fileXml)



#cycle for test dir   
for x in range(countForTest):

    fileJpg = choice(imgs) # get name of random image from origin dir
    fileXml = fileJpg[:-4] +'.xml' # get name of corresponding annotation file

    #move both files into train dir
    shutil.move(os.path.join(crsPath, fileJpg), os.path.join(testPath, fileJpg))
    shutil.move(os.path.join(crsPath, fileXml), os.path.join(testPath, fileXml))

    #remove files from arrays
    imgs.remove(fileJpg)
    xmls.remove(fileXml)

#rest of files will be validation files, so rename origin dir to val dir
os.rename(crsPath, valPath)

#summary information after splitting
print('Total images: ', totalImgCount)
print('Images in train dir:', len(os.listdir(trainPath))/2)
print('Images in test dir:', len(os.listdir(testPath))/2)
print('Images in validation dir:', len(os.listdir(valPath))/2)
```

Comment: your approach has a bug: because of the way you use random choice, you're destined to have same files present in more than one set (e.g. training and testing)

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to split folders of images into train/test using the split-folders library

```py
import splitfolders


input_folder = 'path/'


# Split with a ratio.
# To only split into training and validation set, set a tuple to `ratio`, i.e, (.8, .2).
# Train, val, test
splitfolders.ratio(input_folder, 
                   output="cell_images2", 
                   seed=42, 
                   ratio=(.7, .2, .1), 
                   group_prefix=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this easy method to split folders of images into train/test/val using the split-folders library. If you are new to this library, you have to install it first using the pip command: `pip install split-folders`

```
import splitfolders

image_directory= r'C:\Users\ugoch\Desktop\16 OBU students_Model\CNN from scratch\data_mv'
splitfolders.ratio(image_directory, output="output",
        seed=42, ratio=(0.7, 0.15, 0.15), group_prefix=None, move=False) # default values
```

Copying files: 48 files [00:00, 843.49 files/s]