# The accuracy of fit_generator and fit is different

Tags: python, keras

++ The fit_generator has been modified to fit.

The total number of DataSets is 12,507, True is 6,840 and False is 7,056.

The Data Set configuration is the same.
The model is the same.

A Model is :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(192, 112, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
.
.
.
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=15, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2, verbose=2)
```

The accuracy when using fit is close to 100%.

B Modeil is :

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
TRAIN_PATH,
target_size=(192, 112),
classes=['true', 'false'],
class_mode='categorical',
batch_size=64,
color_mode='grayscale',
shuffle=True)

val_gen = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
VAL_PATH,
target_size=(192, 112),
classes=['true', 'false'],
class_mode='categorical',
batch_size=64,
color_mode='grayscale',
shuffle=False)

test_gen = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
VAL_PATH,
target_size=(192, 112),
classes=['true', 'false'],
class_mode='categorical',
batch_size=64,
color_mode='grayscale',
shuffle=False)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(192, 112, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
.
.
.
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
          loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(
train_gen,
validation_data=val_gen,
epochs=15,
steps_per_epoch=len(train_gen)//64,  # 64 is the batch_size
validation_steps=len(val_gen)//64,
verbose=2)

model.evaluate(test_gen,
           batch_size=64,
           verbose=2)
```

In this case, the accuracy is close to 50%.

Isn't A model and B model the same way?
Why do other precisions come out?

++
Here's how to load data from the A model:

```
true_Data_list = np.array(os.listdir(TRUE_DIR))
false_Data_list = np.array(os.listdir(FALSE_DIR))

 # -------------------------------- Load True Set ----------------------------------------- #
for index in range(len(true_Data_list)):  # 이미지 폴더 리스트 만들기
    path_true = os.path.join(TRUE_DIR, true_Data_list[index])
    image_true = ImageOps.grayscale(Image.open(path_true))  # True 이미지
    image_true = np.reshape(np.asarray(image_true), (192, 112, 1)).astype(np.float32)
    data_X.append([np.array(image_true)])
    data_Y.append([1, 0])
```

Load False Set is repeated in the same way.

Then I will reshape and split.

```
data_X = np.reshape(data_X, (-1, 192, 112, 1)).astype(np.float32)
data_Y = np.reshape(data_Y, (-1, 2)).astype(np.int8)

train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y = train_test_split(data_X, data_Y, test_size=0.25, shuffle=True, random_state=625)
```

In the case of B model

```
TRAIN_PATH = 'dataset/train'
VAL_PATH = 'dataset/val'
TEST_PATH = 'dataset/test'
```

The created PATH will now be in

```
train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_PATH, ...
```

with each PATH having true and false folders

The photo is to be output via verbose = 2 in 1 epoch.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j1kz.png)

Comment: You are using different batch sizes, batch size is not the same as steps.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy : I changed batch size and various things.
But the result is still the same.
Can you confirm that you have created a new sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fit_generator` is deprecated. Although they should give the slightly same results. You have a typo(?) I think,

```
train_batch_size = len(train_X) // 64
test_batch_size = len(test_X) // 64
```

They supposed to be the `steps_per_epoch`, while fitting you set them as `batch_size`. I am not sure whether you augmented data in both cases but in the first approach you use a high batch size. The data points you see in an epoch is different in both cases. Second approach seems more reliable, you can use `fit()` with generators also.

Comment: I changed it to fit in the code using fit_generator and changed batch_size to 64.

Comment: The first experiment gave good results, but the second experiment did not. 
Corrected the sentence. Is there anything I can confirm?

Comment: I am not sure about your model, you passed the `class_mode = 'categorical'`, did you use softmax in the last dense with 2 neurons?

Comment: yes, I just added a model on the 4th line.

Comment: Sorry I missed it, `model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))` does not make sense. You need to change either `model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))` with `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` or change `class_mode = 'binary'` with `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))`. 2 neurons and sigmoid contradict with each other at the last dense layer.

Comment: I modified the code as follows: 
`model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])`

However, the accuracy is the same for both models.

Comment: They are supposed be the same, I mean `fit` and `fit_generator`. The way you use softmax and loss is correct now.

Comment: I fixed the overall sentence. Since fit_generator has been changed to fit, it has been changed to A model and B model. I hope both models will produce results like this. 

Your answer was really helpful, but why can you tell the results are different?

Comment: `test_gen = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(VAL_PATH, ... )` I don't know if you have a test directory, if you have, you seem to passed it wrong. Otherwise can you explicitly write training, validation, and testing accuracies for both cases? They seem same to me actually.

Comment: Oh ..... I miscut. The test directory was wrong, but the acc and val_acc after the second epoch are all 50.77% and 50.79% in B model. 
After changing the test directory appropriately, the test acc is 50.78%.

Comment: It may be because when you set shuffle true for training but not for validation. I assume data is ordered. Did you wait for all epochs to end? Model A and Model B should roughly generate the same results.

Comment: I refer to Steven White's article on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074712/how-to-split-folder-of-images-into-test-training-validation-sets-with-stratified)

The train, val, and test folders were all shuffled and waited until epoch was finished.

Maybe it's because the number of data is small? Isn't the number of data related to the use of generator?

Comment: Number of data seems OK for binary classification, 50% accuracy is just random guessing which does not make sense, at least it might be like 60%-70%. It might be related to how you load your data in Model A, Model B requires sub-directories to pass it to model.

Comment: Now I added a way to load data from Model A.  And Model B has true and false directories for train, val and test respectively.

Comment: Sometimes I become blind sorry for that, generator is already batched, if you print `len(train_gen)` you will see the steps actually. For example 1200 data with a batch_size = 20 will make generator length 60. When you again divide it to batch size when fitting, you are using very less data for training that makes it random guessing. Try not to specify steps_per_epoch in Model B, that should do it.

Comment: And I changed model.fit and model.evaluate to `history = model.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=15, verbose=2)` and `model.evaluate(test_gen, verbose=2)`.
The result is 50% as before.  len(train_gen) is 131. Then, the number of times (?) Appearing via verbose = 1 is 33. If possible with a photo, I will attach a photo.

Comment: Can you try again with `steps_per_epoch = 130` in Model B?

Comment: Yes, I used `history = model.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, steps_per_epoch=130, epochs=15, verbose=2)` and it's the same as the attached photo.

Comment: If the accuracy is still same with `steps_per_epoch = 130`, I am out of ideas sorry.

Comment: Can I ask only one at the end?
Why did the attached photo take 33 times when I used steps_per_epoch = 130?

And Thank you for worrying about the problem together. Really.

Comment: Yes that's the case actually it should take 33 points which causing model to see less data that yielding to low accuracy. Maybe you can try with lower batch sizes like 32 if that effects steps. I thought it should take `len(train_gen)` steps. Also what does generator prints like, xx images found belonging to 2 classes? How many images does it have?

Comment: Yes, Generator prints
Found 8337 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 2085 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 3474 images belonging to 2 classes.

Maybe you need it, so create len (train_gen), len (val_gen), len (test_gen).
The order is 261, 66, 109.

And the accuracy of the result of changing the batch size to 32 is the same, but 33 points has changed to 66 points.

Comment: I am really not sure how it is forcing itself to have 33 steps even if you set steps to 131. You can try [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/master/ml/pc/exercises/image_classification_part1.ipynb) yourself to how batch_size and steps_per_epoch effects training. I played with batch_size etc. it gave me expected steps. Also 33 steps with a batch with 64 means, 64*33 = 2112 samples.  So for this last issue, I don't have an idea. But I'd happy if you can upvote the answer.

Comment: The upvote hits the green V-shape on the left of Answer?
If it's correct, I've already checked. Thank you again.